# debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method (ssh authentication via pub key)

Tags: 18.04, ssh

I am trying to get authentication via public key working. I ran:

```
ssh justin@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx -vv
```

It returned:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/justinobrien/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:.............
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/justinobrien/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/justinobrien/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/justinobrien/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/justinobrien/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I have the following in my `.ssh/` directory:

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
justin
justin.pub
known_hosts
root
root.pub
```

One public and private key for user 'justin'. And a pair for 'root'. Each public key is stored in the respected users 'authorized_keys' file on the ubuntu server. I am not sure what the `id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub`(I think a key I generated whose name I never changed) and `known_hosts` files are on my local computer. I am also not sure where any of the `id_dsa`, `id_ecdsa`, `id_ed25519`, `id_xmss` files are coming from, as they do not appear to be in this directory. Anyone know what is going on or what the next step would be in figuring out why I can only authenticate via password?

Comment: If you want to use an identityfile with a name other than the default `id_rsa` then you will need to specify that on the command line with the `-i` switch ex. `ssh -i ~/.ssh/justin justin@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` (or equivalently set up a `~/.ssh/config` entry with this information for the target server)

Comment: @steeldriver  Just went back to watch the tutorial I am following to ensure that I am not crazy, and he indeed does not do this, think he left the ./ssh/config part out. Anyway, wound up learning a lot more than I would have on the way. This is all working and actually makes sense, thanks.